# How do I put together this docker-compose.yml properly?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus

In this docker-compose.yaml I tried to combine prometheus, grafana and my app in one compose file.
I don't have much experience with prometheus and docker-compose so I decided to post my first question on stack.
I tried to pull metrics from docker container with docker-compose prometheus but it doesn't work. Most likely they operate in different networks.

```
version: '3.7'

volumes:
    prometheus_data: {}
    grafana_data: {}

networks:
  front-tier:
  back-tier:

services:
  fastapi:
    image: tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8
    ports:
        - 80:80
    volumes:
        - ./app:/app
    working_dir: /app
    command:
        - 'pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt'
        - 'uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80'
    restart: always
    
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.1.0
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles'
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    networks:
      - back-tier
    restart: always
  node-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
    command: 
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc' 
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - --collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points
      - "^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc|rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers|rootfs/var/lib/docker/overlay2|rootfs/run/docker/netns|rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs)($$|/)"
    ports:
      - 9100:9100
    networks:
      - back-tier
    restart: always
    deploy:
      mode: global
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    user: "472"
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
      - ./grafana/provisioning/:/etc/grafana/provisioning/
    env_file:
      - ./grafana/config.monitoring
    networks:
      - back-tier
      - front-tier
    restart: always
```

The warning I get once I do `docker-compose up`

`ERROR: for fastapi  Cannot start service fastapi: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown. ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.`

Comment: All the files and folders are in the same folder.

Comment: https://dev.to/aheissenberger/docker-fails-with-oci-runtime-create-failed-4e3l

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because of the command provided for `fastapi`.

The `command` config in docker-compose overrides the default command and can only have one command instruction.
Documentations:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

The way you formed the service for fastapi needs to be updated:

Extend the image `tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn:python3.8` by using a dockerfile and use it to install requirements.txt and run the server.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn:python3.8

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./app /app

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

and update docker-compose for fastapi. Add any additional configurations for fastapi.

```yaml
services:
  fastapi:
    build: .
    ports:
        - 80:80
    restart: always
    # add network configuration if needed
```

You can find more about [uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker) on README [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: You do not need the `volumes:` block, since the code is already in the Docker image (having it means that you are not running the code built into the image, which means you'll be running an untested image when you go to deploy the application).  If you're using the default name `Dockerfile` (with a capital `D`) then you can also use a shorthand `build: .` syntax.

Comment: @David Maze yes, you are right. Correct me if I'm wrong about volumes. By mounting i can have the fastapi have the latest code without restarting the service, right? The image would have the latest code only once it's built. So, instead of restarting and building image for every changes that I make wouldn't the volume mounting help?

Comment: You have to restart the application every time, no matter what.  If you're going to use a volume to overwrite the entire application content in the image, then a lighter-weight setup like a Python virtual environment will let you run your native-host code without rebuilding a Docker image, but still have its installation separated from other Pythons.

Comment: For me, running the docker alone, without docker-compose leads to the same error, so it's not likely that it's due to the command in docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution to this works perfectly but  to have the fastapi display the latest code without restarting the service you need to mount a volume like:

```
services:
  fastapi:
    build: .
    ports:
        - 80:80
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/fastapi
```

For the Dockerfile, you need to add the --reload flag in the CMD command

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80", "--reload"]
```